# When should the seeding of Mersenne-twister happen to make the application secure?

Tags: prng

I want to create an online roulette game.
Is it OK if the PRNG is seeded only once, when the user starts the game?
Or is it recommended to re-seed sometimes during game?
Maybe just seeded once a day on the server and every players would get a next random number without re-seeding?
How would you do? How do they do it at online casinos?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the quality of your seeds. Seeding every day with numbers from another PRNG doesn't make much sense imho, but TRNG seeds might make sense. On a different note, there is [the Crypto SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/), you might get quality answers there.

Comment: (Thanks for the link.)
I can seed it with large numbers requested from a website, quite good quality, not TRNG, but better then the result of a normal rand() function.